# Response не отдаёт данные в другой класс

Tags: java, android, android-volley

```
public class AllPrices {

    private String price;

    public AllPrices(Context context, String userLevel) {
        getPricesForAmortizators(context, userLevel);
    }

    public void getPricesForAmortizators(Context context, final String userLevel){
        //final String number = artNumber.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", ""); // удалится все кроме букв и цифр;
        final String number = "82501004";

        final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.PRICE_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response){
                        try {
                            JSONObject src = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray prices = src.getJSONArray("prices");

                           setPrice(getAmortPrices(prices));
                           System.out.println("1111111111111111111" + "   " + getPrice());

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams()
            {
                Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("number", number);
                params.put("userLevel", userLevel);

                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue queue = VolleyRequestHelper.getInstance(context).getRequestQueue();
        VolleyRequestHelper.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }

    private String getAmortPrices(JSONArray prices){
        try {
            return prices.getJSONObject(0).getString("price");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

что я делаю не так, не могу получить в другом классе 
вот это

```
price_euro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (user.getLevel().length() > 2){

                    AllPrices allprice = new AllPrices(context, user.getLevel());

                    String price = allprice.getPrice();}
```

получаю NULL
ответ приходит сто процентов в AllPrices, проверил элементарным `System.out.println("1111111111111111111" + "   " + getPrice());`, но я его не вижу в другом классе

Comment: Запрос в сеть идёт в другом потоке и непредсказуемо долго. На момент вашего обращения к `.getPrice()` запрос ещё не успел отработать. Пишите код, учитывая асинхронность получения данных.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста куда что вписать, вообще не пойму. Я так и понял что просто когда я читаю значение его не ещё.

Comment: Парой строк тут не ограничиться... У вас в принципе логика неправильно написано. Запускать запрос в сеть в конструкторе модели данных - неправильно. Вам надо примерно так сделать: 1. По клику запустить запрос в сеть, а не создавать экземпляр класса. 2. В onResponse создать экземпляр класса, наполнить его полученными данными. Теперь можно с этим экземпляром работать. 3. Соответственно код запроса в сеть из класса-модели нужно убрать.

Comment: `public void onResponse(String response){
                            JSONObject src = new JSONObject(response);
                            final JSONArray amortPrice = src.getJSONArray("prices");
                            System.out.println("Response");

                            AllPrices allPrices = new AllPrices(context, userLevel);
                            allPrices.setPrice(allPrices.getAmortPrices(amortPrice));
                            System.out.println("1111111111111111111" + "   " + allPrices.getPrice());
                    }`
перенёс... не то всеравно

Comment: а вот 
`public void onClick(View v) {
  
                        AllPrices ap = new AllPrices();
                        ap.getPricesForAmortizators(context, user.getLevel());

                        String price = ap.getPrice();`
как без создания экземпляра? статический метод использовать? пробовал. Разницы нет.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб что то не получается, при клике запускается циклически этот код и не останавливается сам

Answer (score 0):

Загрузка данных из сервера происходит в другом потоке, поэтому вам нужно написать callback для получение результата при успешном завершении запроса

На пример

```
interface Callback {
       void onDone(AllPrices prices);
    }

void getPrices(Callback callback) {
.....
//Вставьте в параметр то что вы получили
callback(...)
}
```

Comment: Пытаюсь понять ваш ответ, но не могу.

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду, в callback(...) вставить параметр... как я в него вставлю это же не метод?
И откуда это всё и как я могу вызвать по onClick()
Я при создании класса передаю туда ещё параметры
AllPrices(Context context, String userLevel) 
как с ними быть?

Answer (score 0):

Вобщем решил я поступить так... Всеравно мне нужен результат этого запроса вывести в Toast.. поэтому я перенёс реализацию его в onResponce

```
price_euro.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (user.getLevel().length() > 2){

                AllPrices ap = new AllPrices();
                ap.getPricesForAmortizators(context, user.getLevel(), art_number.getText().toString());
            }
        });
```

а остальное в другом классе.
Всё работает как и хотел!